# why is python 2.7 "Acting" like python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, textwrangler

i just started learning Python (w no prior programing experience whatsoever) so i was asked to get TextWrangler and type: `print "hello world"` (of course) and then RUN it through Terminal app on Mac. i was also asked to use Python 2.7 NOT Python 3!!! but when i wrote the line as i was told to on the video `print "Hello World"` the Terminal app showed a syntax err! when i wrote the line `print ("hello world")` then it went through with no problem and was executed by Terminal. why is my python 2.7 acting like python 3, if i can put it that way? When i type `python --version` in terminal it shows that i run 2.7 version. Thanks.

Comment: Try to run `python --version` in console, and what does it say?

Comment: Did you import `from __future__ import print_function`?

Comment: If you could show a full transcript of the shortest possible REPL session showing this behavior, **including the banner that Python prints when started with the active version number**, that would be helpful. (It would also answer the question Alex asked, since such a transcript would show everything you'd entered necessary to cause the error).

Comment: ...that way we'd know that the Python interpreter running `python --version` and the Python interpreter that gave you an error are the same one (you can have more than one version of Python installed on the same machine!)

Comment: your IDE is linked to python 3 somehow. Try `python -c "print 'hello world'"`

Comment: it's in the last sentence in my question, when i type python --version in terminal shows me Python 2.7.13
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 12:39:47)

Comment: I have no idea what from __future__ import print_function is. do i run this line into Terminal or the text editor? kilojoules, when i run the line in terminal, hello world prints as next line.

Answer (score -1):

You can explicitly request the python 2 shell over conflicting versions in terminal like so:

```
alias python='python2'
```